# Dealing with the remote notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

I have four screen in my application namely **A,B,C,D** .**A** is my **first screen of the application appeared when application launch**.Suppose C and D screens showing some data which are subscribed for the remote notifications in two different channels .with same client key and application id.

1. When remote notification come it is showing first screen i.e.A when
   I tapped on  notification.I want to show screen C or D as per type of the notification.
2. What is the con taint of the NSDictionary userInfo in the method

   **application:(UIApplication *)application
       didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo**

Comment: If you found a answer to be correct, would you mind marking it as correct.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you would like to see the contents of a directory, just use NSLog.  In this case, add the following code to the -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method.

```
NSLog("UserInfo: %@", userInfo);
```

That will print the contents of the directory to the log.  Sorry I didn't give a more specific answer, the question was somewhat vague.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

To show the screen C or D, check for application state in didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
   if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
       // check for condition for screen C or D and according to your condition redirect user to that screen.
   }
}
```